# Opening a webpage certain times in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to open a webpage certain number of times, for example I want to open a webpage 10 times. I made this code but I can't control how many times.

```
import webbrowser
x = 'http://www.google.com'
for eachTime in x:
       webbrowser.open(x)
```

Comment: Using `for eachTime in x:` will go through the loop once for each item in `x`.  That means that you will open the tab as many times as `x` has characters.

Comment: How do I change this to number of time (integers) instead of characters?

Answer (score 1):

You might just want this!

```
for _ in range(10):
    webbrowser.open(x)
```

`_` acts as counter variable which ranges from 0 to 9. (We call it `_` to indicate that we don't care the actual values 0 to 9, we just want to do the thing inside the loop ten times.)

Comment: Sorry but what is _ ?

Comment: @John a variable name, used when we don't care about what is in that variable. This is exactly the same as doing `for i in range(10):...`